# Make image follow cursor when hovering over an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering whether it is possible with JavaScript to create a `<a>` element which at hover would display an image that follows the position of the mouse.

I found a lot of solutions for the hover part, but I haven't found any which would also follow the mouse.

In other words, on hover, the image doesn't follow the mouse but just appears and dissapears on hover, how can I modify my code in order to make it follow the mouse? This is what I have tried so far :

```html
<a href="link.html" onmouseover="document.getElementById('hoverimage').style.display = 'block';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('hoverimage').style.display = 'none';">hoverlink</a>

<div style="display: none;" id="hoverimage">
   <img src="image.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at this codepen https://codepen.io/redspiderfish/pen/MYmeYz

Comment: Using the codepen above i have editted to do the job you was looking for. Check my codepen out: https://codepen.io/HeeneyOG/pen/PoJgmNz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the clientX and clientY positions of the mouse, and set the `top` and `left` style positions of the image to those.

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="interval()">Link</a>

function interval() {
    while (true) {
        setInterval(showImage, 1);
    }
}

function showImage() {

    var x = clientX;
    var y = clientY;
    var image = document.getElementById("hoverimage");
    image.style.left = x;
    image.style.top = y;
 }
```

Once you hover on the link, the image will move to the mouse's position once a millisecond, forever.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You need to get mouse's clientX and clientY position when hovering over certain element (body, div, etc.) and add that coordinates to your created image